# Quais as diferenças entre o npm e o Yarn?

Tags: npm, yarn

Estou pensando em migrar do **npm** para o **Yarn**, alguém pode me dizer quais as principais diferenças?

Existe algum beneficio considerável entre os dois?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/pt-BR/) e [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) são gestores de pacotes, que cumprem basicamente a mesma missão.

O Yarn [nasceu dentro do facebook](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1840075619545360) e devido a alguma frustração por a NPM iterar lentamente e estar a ficar lenta. Isto veio a ser corrigido, talvez por influência de concurrência Yarn.

Para uma comparação mais exaustiva teríamos de comparar versão a versão de NPM e Yarn. Mas basicamente fazem o mesmo, e (por enquanto) são compatíveis pois ambas usam o `package.json` como fonte de informação de que pacotes e versões o projeto precisa. Mas atenção: como ambas escrevem (e apagam) pacotes/programas do diretório `node_modules` pode acontecer que um instale/apague versões especificas que o outro instalou/removeu.

## Diferenças na API:

```
           NPM  |  YARN

       npm init | yarn init
npm install ... | yarn add ...
 npm update ... | yarn upgrade ...
 npm remove ... | yarn remove ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Alguns pontos que considero importantes.

#### Determinismo

No ecossistema Node, dependências são colocadas dentro de um diretório chamado `node_modules` no seu projeto. No entanto, essa estrutura de arquivo pode ser diferente da árvore de dependência real, pois as dependências duplicadas são mescladas. O cliente `npm` instala dependências no diretório `node_modules` de forma **não determinística**. Isso significa que, baseado na ordem em que as dependências são instaladas, a estrutura de um diretório `node_modules` pode ser diferente de uma pessoa para outra. Essas diferenças podem causar erros do tipo "funciona na máquina" que demoram muito para serem descobertos.

Com `yarn`, você sempre sabe que está recebendo o mesmo conteúdo em cada máquina de desenvolvimento. `yarn` utiliza *lockfiles* e um algoritmo de instalação que é **determinístico** e confiável. Estes *lockfiles* bloqueiam as dependências instaladas em uma versão específica, garantindo que cada instalação resulte na mesma estrutura de arquivos em `node_modules` em todas as máquinas.

#### Paralelização

`yarn` é capaz de paralelizar operações, maximizando a utilização de recursos e fazendo com que o processo de instalação seja mais rápido.

#### Recursos

A rede é utilizada mais eficientemente pelo `yarn`. Há um cacheamento global de cada pacote que é baixado, assim você só baixa cada pacote uma única vez. Além disso, é possível que faça [melhor uso de outros recursos do sistema (como RAM)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43987433/114900).

**Fontes**

1. [When to use Yarn over NPM? What are the differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40028313/3551913)
2. [Yarn: A new package manager for JavaScript](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1840075619545360)
3. [README.md do repositório Yarn no GitHub](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/blob/master/README.md)